# AJAX Chat - ORDER BY date, time (Messages appear from bottom, and the toppest will get deleted)?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a chat application I have been developing:

http://driptone.com/jony/applications/chat/index.php

Problem is, I am limiting results of messages at 30 messages maximum.
I want new messages to overwrite, so the oldest messages will get deleted, from the top.

But for some reason, the messages on the bottom, which are the new ones, get deleted instead? By deleted I mean, won't show.

How can I change it?

I am ordering by date, time:

```
SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY date, time ASC LIMIT 30
```

Inside while loop:

```
echo 
'
    <li>
        <div class="messages">
            <p>
                '.$row['message'].'
            </p>
            <span class="user-meta">
                '.$row['username'].'
            </span>
            <span class="time-meta">
                '.$row['time'].', '.$row['date'].'
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
';
```

***Any ideas?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from(SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY date, time desc LIMIT 30) as main order by date,time asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY date, time ASC LIMIT 30

should be

select * from(SELECT * FROM `messages`  order by `datesale` desc,`timesale` desc limit 30) as m order by `date`,`time`
```

Comment: Yes, but then they will appear from the top. I want it to be like skype. bottom = new messages